# git commit error: pathspec 'commit' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, command-line

I am trying to upload a Ruby app to Heroku. I start with `git init` and then I type `git add .` and then I use `git commit -m initial commit`.

Whenever I use `git commit -m`, I receive an error message saying:

> git commit error:pathspect 'commit' did not match any file(s) known to git.

I have been told that this is happening because the arguments are in the wrong order.

The thing I noticed is that when I use `git add .` it will not list the files that are being added because it will just go to the next line.

I suspect that I am having this problem because my files are not really being added.

I would appreciate any advice about how to correct this problem.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

The command line arguments are separated by space. If you want provide an argument with a space in it, you should quote it. So use `git commit -m "initial commit"`.

Comment: git commit -m 'initial commit' single quote was not working for me, I am using it in a windows env.

Comment: On Windows, double quotes are the only choice.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved this thing with double quote in my window system.

Comment: Day saver, I did not use (double-single) quotes at all, so it failed because of spaces.

Answer (score 89):

I would just like to add--

In **windows the commit message should be in double quotes** (`git commit -m "initial commit"` instead of `git commit -m 'initial commit'`), as I spent about an hour, just to figure out that single quote is not working in windows.

Comment: Windows users look here!

Comment: Coming from [GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/) where quotes are single.

Comment: I am using git commit -m "first commit" and still getting the same error on Windows.

Comment: @nicks Thank you sir!

Comment: yep, coming from bitbucket help, which also cited single quotes

Comment: @KirillYunussov: same here. I found this issue when I was following the Learn Git tutorial in Bitbucket: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/learn-git-with-bitbucket-cloud

Answer (score 10):

In my case, this error was due to special characters what I was considering double quotes as I copied the command from a web page.

Answer (score 8):

I figured out mistake here use double quotations instead of single quotations.

change this

`git commit -m 'initial commit'`

to

`git commit -m "initial commit"`

Answer (score 4):

Had this happen to me when committing from Xcode 6, after I had added a directory of files and subdirectories to the project folder. The problem was that, in the Commit sheet, in the left sidebar, I had checkmarked not only the root directory that I had added, but all of its descendants too. To solve the problem, I checkmarked only the root directory. This also committed all of the descendants, as desired, with no error.

Answer (score 4):

I have encounter the same problem. my syntax has no problem. 
What I found is that I copied and pasted **git commit -m "comments"** from my note. I retype it, the command execute without issue. It turns out the **-** and **" "** are the problem when I copy paste to terminal.

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Had this happen to me when committing from Xcode 6, after I had added a directory of files and subdirectories to the project folder.  The problem was that, in the *Commit* sheet, in the left sidebar, I had checkmarked not only the root directory that I had added, but all of its descendants too.  To solve the problem, I checkmarked only the root directory.  This also committed all of the descendants, as desired, with no error.

Answer (score 2):

Type the command `git commit -m "Initial Commit"` yourself in the terminal/command prompt instead of copy and paste from web page. I believe this will help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was I used wrong alias for `git commit -m`. I used `gc`alias which dit not meant `git commit -m`

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Here is how I solved this issue:

1. Made an app on Heroku first and prepared all the codes in local_folder to push into it.
2. Cloned the remote app using `heroku git:clone -a app_name`
3. then `cd app_name`
4. then copied all the codes into this folder from local_folder
5. then `git add .`
6. then `git commit -am "initial commit"`
7. then `git push heroku master`
8. Viola!

Answer (score 0):

if there are anybodys using python os to invoke git,u can use os.system('git commit -m " '+str(comment)+'"')

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was I had forgotten to add the switch -m before the quoted comment. It may be a common error too, and the error message received is exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. `"` or `'` doesn't work for me.

In my case, i used `git commit` to add commit-msg. After this commit, `git commit -m 'xxx'` works as before.