# I can`t coop with my Git. errors when git commit and git add so I can`t even do my task

Tags: git, commit

When I try to commit, it says

> error: pathspec '1st commit' did not match any file(s) known to git

When I try to add files, it says nothing.
When I try to add branches, it says

> fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it new folder or the error is in existing folder? If it is existing git repo than try `git fetch` and `git checkout`. If it is new repo than `git init` and `git remote add "url"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git commit error: pathspec 'commit' did not match any file(s) known to git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951207/git-commit-error-pathspec-commit-did-not-match-any-files-known-to-git)

Comment: If the above link doesn't help, please post more information about what commands you are using, etc.

Comment: Please share the commands you use (and *where* you used them), this looks like a syntax problem.

Comment: at first, I use ' git init ', then ' git add . ' and at last ' git commit "1st commit" '

Comment: Your last command should be git commit -m "1st commit"

Comment: Did your `git init ` worked or was there any error?

Comment: no, now it works properly

Answer (score 0):

1. `git commit` opens an editor for messages. Use `-m` to pass them on the command line. But try to prefer editing them for real. Good, descriptive commits have saved my bacon a few times. Bad ones slow down my productivity when I’m trying to understand something and `git blame` is suddenly useless. Write good messages. Your future self and your coworkers will thank you.
2. `git add` needs pathspecs, and branches aren’t pathspecs.

Comment: https://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html