# fatal: paths 'commit ...' with -a does not make sense ,how can I solve this problem?

Tags: git, git-commit

I have been working on a flutter project in between I tried to initialise git on that project.
first I used `git init` and then `git add --all`.All the changes are visible on `git status`. Then I user git commit -m 'commit message' and got this error-`error: pathspec 'commit' did not match any file(s) known to git`
so i used-`git commit -a -m 'commit message'`.so i got this error

how can I commit all these changes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+pathspec+commit+did+not+match+any+file%28s%29+known+to+git

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VSCode or Android Studio as your IDE you can try using the VersionControl tool built in and will help you with that.
For your first commit you could use something like this: `git commit -m "initial commit"`.

Also, possible duplicate of this: [git commit error: pathspec 'commit' did not match any file(s) known to git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951207/git-commit-error-pathspec-commit-did-not-match-any-files-known-to-git)

Comment: it was the issue of using single quotes for the comment.